# Initial connecting of two computers through a server, but allowing them to connect directly afterwards

Tags: networking, network-programming

Two computers in separate NAT networks, wants to connect with each other.
No port forwarding can be made.

We can connect between them using a intermediate server, however we dont want the entire communication to go through this server after the initial connectivity.

Is there any way that the intermediate server can perform the initial connection and then allow them to continue their communication directly somehow ?

Everything I know about computer networks say 'no', however I though I'll give this question a try here.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done vía [NAT traversal techniques](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). It isn't simple but many applications do it, e.g. Skype, where channeling all communication through a server would be innefective.